# Splitting a string and adding to array

Tags: php, string, split

I have some data that is posted from a java application to a php page. The data is posted in the form of a string of numbers, each seperated by a comma - e.g. "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8". The string could have different amounts of numbers there is nothing definite. I know how to split the string up but how would I go about adding it to an array in PHP? I'm completely new to PHP!

Answer (score 7):

You could use the function `explode()`. Have a look at the [manual](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

For example:

```
$str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8";
$arr = explode(',', $str);
```

Answer (score 4):

just use the function explode

look at http://php.net/explode

Answer (score 0):

If you "know how to split the string up", then you already know that [this process *produces* an array](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).