# how can I slice a string and append into a array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I need slice a string and append intro a array, the string is like this:

```
"stringPartOne stringPartTwo stringPartThree"
```

I want to have a array like this:

```
['stringPartOne', 'stringPartTwo', 'stringPartThree']
```

How can I slice this string and append into a array considering that the number of elements is dynamic

Comment: `$arr = explode(" ", $str)`?

Comment: Show your [mcve].

Comment: @jdv the question is very simple, if you need my Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example probably can not help me, but thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a string and adding to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485136/splitting-a-string-and-adding-to-array)

Comment: @TheDev read [ask]. A [mcve] is almost always requested. The idea is you show what you have done first.

Comment: I tried this but what I had ready exactly what I posted, a string where I needed it to become an array, sorry but I can not describe what I have better than this

Comment: explode and preg_split are the goto functions in Php for splitting a string by a delimeter.  Use implode to join array parts into a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a formal answer - Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$str = "stringPartOne stringPartTwo stringPartThree";
$arr = explode(" ", $str);
```